# CloudPebble vs. Native Pebble SDK

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

i'm considering starting pebble development but i'm confused on the pebble website(https://developer.getpebble.com) they advertise for [Cloud Pebble](http://cloudpebble.net) but they also recommend installing it through command line on a computer. Whats the difference? Are there advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both allow you to do the same things. Each has some advantages and limitations. They are both fully supported by Pebble (Pebble recently hired @katharine who wrote CloudPebble).

#### [CloudPebble](https://cloudpebble.net/ide/)

- You do not need to install anything on your computer
- It works on any platform with a browser (Windows/Mac/Linux, iPad, etc)

#### [Download SDK](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/)

- You get to use your own text editor
- You can work offline
- You can customize the build process if you need to (through the `wscript` build file for [`waf`](https://code.google.com/p/waf/))
- Only works on Linux and Mac